# Loaded table rows don't have css from table class

Tags: jquery, html, css, ajax

I have a table:

```
 <table class="table-hover table table-bordered">
    <tr>
        <th>
            Table headers
        </th>
        ....
        <th></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            ID
        </td>
        ...
    </tr>
    <tr id=Id TD above> <tr>
 </table>
```

and I'm adding new `table rows` with `ajax` call:

```
$("tr").click(function () {
    var Id = $(this).find('td').first().text().trim();
    $.ajax({
        url: "/DeviceInstance/LoadPartialData",
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data:  JSON.stringify({id: Id}) ,
        error: function (data) {
            alert("wystąpił nieokreślony błąd " + data);
        },
        success: function (data) {
            $('#' + Id).after().html(data);
            $('#' + Id).fadeToggle("slow", "linear");
        }
    });
```

But rows added by ajax are mising css from assingment to `table table-hover table-bordered` classes on `table`

Is there any way to refresh it?

http://jsfiddle.net/LW3Lm/

Comment: Share the css you have applied

Comment: Can you show the CSS too as that is the likely cause?

Comment: It's can be hard because that's a bootstrap classes and their css.

Comment: View your output after adding a row in Chrome F12 debug tools. Copy the HTML, CSS to a JSFiddle.

Comment: `after()` method expects at least one parameter [after()](http://api.jquery.com/after/)

Comment: what does `data` look like and where is it appended as you have no ids in your above html

Comment: I updated question. Data is just <tr> cells</tr> nothing more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are adding few `tr` within existing `td`. You need to append to the `table` or `tbody`. Your output html is just like this:

```
<tr>
    <td>
        <tr><td></td></tr>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Which you don't want.
I think here is what you want....

HTML

```
<table class="table-hover table table-bordered">
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <th>
        Table headers
    </th>

    <th>new</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <b>cell values</b>
    </td>
    <td>
        <b>cell values</b>
    </td>

</tr>
  <tr id="new_id" style="display:none"></tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <b>cell after</b>
    </td>
    <td>
        <b>cell after</b>
    </td>

</tr>
 </tbody></table>
```

JQuery

```
$( "table" ).on( "click", "td", function() {
  var new_trs=$('<tr><td>New 1st Tr</td><td>New 2nd Tr</td></tr>');
  $("#new_id").after(new_trs);
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://www.bootply.com/128586)

Comment: Thx. It's almost working but it appends at the end of the table instead right after the row which is clicked

Comment: for that you need to add `id` or `class` on that specific `row`. Let me do some editing and come back to you.

Comment: Now check That Demo and the Code. I think that is almost your answer. @szpic

Comment: Yes. Thx. Now I only need to work out how to remove those lines on the second click in the line:> Thank You one more time!

Comment: On that case you need to add id or class to rows that are being created on jquery and on second click just hide them grabbing that exact id or class. Just little few codes will do. :D